Which is the correct approach to find if the sequence diverges?
So according to sources such as MathWorld and Wikipedia, as well as various Real Analysis textbooks, a sequence is defined as divergent if it is not convergent.
But here's an interesting problem...
Prove that the sequence $ \{x_n\} = \{(-1)^n\} $ is divergent.
Solution:
The sequence $ \{x_n\} $ is bounded (we can take $ M = 1 $), which prevents us from directly applying the convergence theorem that states every convergent sequence is bounded.
Assume $ a = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n $ exists. Let $ \epsilon = 1 $. Then, there exists a natural number $ K_1 $ such that:
$$
| (-1)^n - a | < 1 \quad \text{for all } n \geq K_1.
$$
For odd $ n $ (where $ n \geq K_1 $), this implies:
$$
| -1 - a | < 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad -2 < a < 0.
$$
For even $ n $ (where $ n \geq K_1 $), we have:
$$
| 1 - a | < 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad 0 < a < 2.
$$
Since $ a $ cannot satisfy both inequalities simultaneously, our assumption that $ \{x_n\} $ converges leads to a contradiction. Therefore, the sequence $ \{x_n\} $ is divergent.
But here's an interesting take...
According to the course book I am currently reading and again many other Real Analysis books and Encyclopaedia of Mathematics, a divergent sequence is defined as one for which
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty \quad \text{or} \quad \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = -\infty.
$$
Both definitions can be connected in a way or other but we have something else to handle currently.
Since
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n
$$
is indeterminate, the sequence $ \{x_n\} = \{(-1)^n\} $ is neither convergent nor divergent according to this definition.
This discrepancy raises confusion regarding which definition is more appropriate. If the latter definition holds, then the initial problem makes no sense.
Why is there no, one concrete definition about this topic in mathematics? Different sources and different books gives different definitions. This ambiguity is perplexing, especially since I have not encountered similar issues previously. Which approach should I adopt, and which definition is ultimately correct (or more correct)? I understand that there can be multiple ways to prove or disprove a mathematical statement, which is why I'm seeking clarification on this problem. As I'm new to Real Analysis, I am not aware of any other approaches through which I can try to solve this problem.

From my experience, one usually keeps the term "diverges" for when dealing with series (or integrals), and instead mainly talks about whether a limit exists or not. At the end of the day it's just terminology, and regardless of whether you say ${(-1)^n}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ diverges or not, there is still no ambiguity in whether its limit exists

The sequence ${(-1)^n}$ is definitely divergent.

The claim that there is "no universally accepted definition" is strange, because there definitely is.  I see nowhere in that link that divergent sequences must head to either $\pm \infty$.

@Randall well yeah, "no universally accepted definition" does sound strange. I wanted to write it differently, I will edit that part. But the conclusion remain the same - different sources provide the different definition which is strange and leads to confusion.

I've not seen a source that gives a different definition.  At least no reliable source.

The sequence is divergent if it is not convergent. There is no ambiguity about what it means for a sequence to converge.

OP has a legit question.  They have a source that gives an incorrect definition of divergence, hence their confusion (warranted).  The source should be cited and included to clarify the question.

Reading the link you've posted, they do not claim that a divergent sequence must head to either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Instead, they give such sequences as examples of sequences that diverge.  The link says that in some cases "one can find infinitely large sequences" that will diverge.  That doesn't mean every divergent sequence must exhibit that behavior.
There is definitely an accepted mathematical notation of "convergence" of a sequence, and the definition is unambiguous and its existence not debatable.

The given link doesn't but I have also written that there are books that gives the same definition. Like, if the limit of a sequence is finite then the sequence is convergent and if the limit is infinite then the sequence is divergent. Wheather those definition are right or not is not up to me, idk and that is why I am asking for clarification here.

I have never seen a book give the definition you claim: cite them and quote them exactly and we'll take a look.  Infinite limit $\Rightarrow$ divergent, but divergent doesn't imply infinite limit.

The one that I currently have in my hand is here. I will try to add another ones when I get a hand on them. (They are from college library and not with me rn.)

That is at best an imprecise source.   It is simply wrong.  If you are reading that you have a right to be confused.

Well, to put it simply, if a sequence does not converge it is called divergent.
A divergent sequence does not have to be unbounded, it just does not have limit.
